# pending payment

Tags: transactions, wallet, blockchain, multibit

Three days ago I sent a payment via my MultiBit wallet but it is still marked as unconfirmed, only 4 confirmations. How long it will take this transaction to become fully confirmed? Thanks.

Comment: It appears from your comment below that your tx was seen by 4 peers. Just to clarify the proper terminology, it has received 0 confirmations, not 4. You only say 4 confirmations if your tx has been included in a block already and three more blocks have been mined.

Comment: MultiBit wallet says: "seen by four peers, not yet confirmed"

Comment: Exactly. "Seen by four peers" != "four confirmations."

Answer (score 1):

Bitcoin transactions are almost instant. Average confirmation time is around 8 minutes, but first confirmation may take an hour and eight confirmations even more. Thing is there is no such thing as fully confirmed transaction. The receiver of bitcoin transaction may decide not accept the transaction before certain amount of confirmations are done to prevent double spending. Bigger transaction fee will increase the transaction confirmation priority, so if you did not pay any transaction fee the confirmations may take quite a while.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. There is no way the receiver to accept/decline the transaction because it is still pending. I paid the fee myself. Here is what the MultiBit says: d94f529838c4d38e30b6b80f97acc9140ab4fcef883b36124d78099ef85d237d: Seen by 4 peers. Pending/unconfirmed. It is very strange for me that i paid too high fee - 0.01BTC

Comment: Will it help if I reset the blockchain/transactions?

Answer (score 0):

Just reset blockchain in the multibit menu. If it doesn't help, you can export private key from the address the tx has been made from, import it on blockchain.info and doublespend it to your own address.